# Weird XY-resolution for map in ArcObjects

Tags: coordinate-system, arcobjects, arcgis-10.6

I have an MXD file with 240 feature-layers, all having the exact same spatial-reference and spatial resolution. I checked this using the following code:

```
var sortedLayers = allLayers.OfType<IGeoFeatureLayer>().Select(x =>
{
    var featureClass = (IGeoDataset) x.FeatureClass;
    return new
    {
        LayerName = x.Name,
        FeatureClass = featureClass,
        Resolution = ((ISpatialReferenceResolution) featureClass.SpatialReference).XYResolution[false]
    };
}).OrderBy(x => x.Resolution);
```

This returns `0.00001` for every layer within my map. However when I query the `XYResolution` for my map I get a really weird number:

```
Console.WriteLine(((ISpatialReferenceResolution)myMap.SpatialReference).XYResolution[false]);
```

This code returns `0.0000000024426994295885463`. First I thought it is a rounding-issue. But the returned resolution is not even **near** the expected resolution of the layers. In fact the nearest decimal that can be represented as binary is `0.00000953674`, which is `0.0000000000000000101` (=`2^-17 + 2^-19`). As far as I know the maps resolution is picked from the layers within that map. However there´s no direct way to query a layer's spatial reference and thus its resolution, as the `SpatialReference`-property on `ILayer` is **write-only**.

Has ayone an idea why the map's resolution is different from my layer's resolution?

The spatial reference of all my layers - or more accurate of their feature-classes - is `DE_DHDN_3GK2`, which is a German
Cartesian coordinate-system on a Bessel elipsoid having metric units. In fact pretty similar to UTM32, however not in tranversal projection. From ArcCatalog:

```
DE_DHDN_3GK2
Berechtigung: Benutzerdefiniert

Projection: Gauss_Kruger
False_Easting: 2500000,0
False_Northing: 0,0
Central_Meridian: 6,0
Scale_Factor: 1,0
Latitude_Of_Origin: 0,0
Linear Unit: Meter (1,0)

Geographic Coordinate System: GCS_Deutsches_Hauptdreiecksnetz
Angular Unit: Degree (0,0174532925199433)
Prime Meridian: Greenwich (0,0)
Datum: D_Deutsches_Hauptdreiecksnetz
  Spheroid: Bessel_1841
    Semimajor Axis: 6377397,155
    Semiminor Axis: 6356078,962818189
    Inverse Flattening: 299,1528128
```

Comment: Resolution of a data source can be impacted by on-the-fly reprojection. Data precision is far more likely to be e+01 or higher.

Comment: @Vince Do you really mean the data-source-projection changes based on the map? That would be annoying, and I doubt that´s what happens. In particular ESRI-docs about the layers `SpatialReference`-property say: "This property is only used for map display, setting this property does not change the spatial reference of the layer's underlying data." (https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#ILayer2_SpatialReference.htm).

Comment: @Vince Anyway: what do you mean by "https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#ILayer2_SpatialReference.htm"? When I look into the datasets spatial-reference I get `0.00001m`, which is exactly what I expected. `e+01` would be pretty low resolution.

Comment: If the the data is in UTM meters and the map in degrees, retaining the resolution value would reduce precision by six orders of magnitude. You haven't provided sufficient details to understand the issue. Name the exact spatial references involved.

Comment: Submillimeter precision is silly since even centimeter accuracy in map data is unlikely. And mapping objects 100 meters across like superhighways only compounds the issue.

Comment: @Vince Sorry, that´s incredible non-sense. Of course you can very accurately **measure** points with even higher resolution. That of course applies just to the **data-resolution**. However to keep things consistent you surely want to enable snapping on this data, won´t you? So you **have** to have such a high resolution in the map as well. In particular when you want to provide topological edits you have to retain that high resolution.

Comment: What is the spatial reference of your DataFrame? This should be set by the first added layer, but can be set before that.

Comment: @Vince I don´t know which layer was added *first*, as I just got that MXD. However the data-frames CRS is also `DE_DHDN_3GK2`. I added its definition into my question.

Comment: If you had no control of the creation of the map canvas, you have no way to know how it came to have the properties is has (nor do we). I suggest you read the [Understanding Coordinate Management in the Geodatabase](https://support.esri.com/en/white-paper/1301) whitepaper, so the values being used in ArcObjects have some context. The snapping tolerance must be at least twice the coordinate precision, and is often 20-200 times larger (less precise).